# Why do i get the error "Cannot autowire service: argument is type-hinted "array", you should configure its value explicitly. "

Tags: symfony, autowired

my service yaml looks like this:

```
App\EventSubscriber\ApiTokenListener:
        autowire: true
        arguments:
            $routesRequiringToken: ['app_authors', 'app_books']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, bind: true }
```

My ApiTokenListener looks like this:

```
    private Session $session;
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;
    private array $routesRequiringToken;

    public function __construct(Session $session, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, array $routesRequiringToken)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->routesRequiringToken = $routesRequiringToken;
    }
```

I defined the array inside the yaml file for the $routesRequiringToken variable. Why do i still get this error?

I tried looking everywhere but can not find a reason why this does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use autowire and extra arguments together and so it is just trying to autowire your array, hence the error. Try removing `autowire: true`, then add the other arguments explicitly like so: `$session: '@session'` and `$urlGenerator: '@router'`.

Answer (score 0):

What it's asking you to do is specify a default. So if you change it to `array $routesRequiringToken = []` this should fix the error, but you might not have access to any parameters still